# can strstr() be used to look for 2 separate key words within a sentence?

Tags: php

can strstr() be used to look for 2 separate key words within a sentence?

ex:

```
$sentence = 'the quick brown fox';

if (strstr($sentence, 'brown') && strstr($sentence, 'fox')) {
   echo 'YES';
} else {
   echo 'NO';
}
```

Comment: I had been using stristr() (the book I'm reading recommended using that to locate a string within a string). It works fine to locate a the occurrence of a single term but I'm not sure if it's working to locate multiple terms.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're using it for. By the look of it you should be using `strpos`, not `strstr`.

Comment: It's for a spider. The occurrence of the 2 terms on the same page is not that common and the only way to find out for sure would be to find the page manually then test it (which would take forever :'( lol).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can ... the Script you have about would return `YES` ..  always because `strstr` is used to Find the first occurrence of a string  and its works independently of other declarations .. it was able to find  `brown` AND `fox` in 2 different first occurrence instance

How they work

```
strstr($sentence, 'brown') // Returns 'brown fox' 
strstr($sentence, 'fox') // Returns 'fox'
```

Both Result are valid Strings

If you try

```
var_dump(strstr($sentence, 'fish')); // Returns false
```

Now this is not an efficient method of checking for string but is has it own uses

Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

**EDIT 1**

```
$sentence = 'the quick brown fox';
$keywords = array (
        'brown',
        'fox' 
);

echo "<pre>";
```

`preg_match` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Example

```
$regex = '/(' . implode ( '|', $keywords ) . ')/i';

if (preg_match ( $regex, $sentence )) // Seach brown or fox
{
    echo "preg_match brown or fox" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

All This would work depending on your use case

`strpos()` - Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in astring

`stripos()` - Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string

`strrpos()` - Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

`strrchr()` - Find the last occurrence of a character in a string

Example

```
if (strpos ( $sentence, $keywords [0] ) || strpos ( $sentence, $keywords [1] )) {
    echo "strpos brown OR fox " . PHP_EOL;
}

if (strripos ( $sentence, $keywords [0] ) && strpos ( $sentence, $keywords [1] )) {
    echo "strpos brown AND fox " . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Would you be able to recommend a better method? I'm still fairly new with PHP so I kind of rely on what I've been reading (which is turning out to not always be the best method :( lol)

Comment: Lol .. ok i'Ll update my answer with some methosd but it would depend on your use case

Comment: It definitely does. THANK YOU! :-D